# Adding Multiple Files To A Jar File, Python

Tags: java, python, jar, zip

So, I made a downloader, that downloads a `.zip` file. Now, I would like to add the contents of that `.zip` file into the `.jar` file.

The `.zip` file contains : Folders, Pictures, Class Files

This is my downloader's code:

```
import urllib2
import os
import shutil
url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29251693/CreeperCraft.zip"
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open('c:\\users\\'+os.environ['USERNAME']+'\\CreeperCraft.zip', 'wb+')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)
file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break
    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
    status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
    print status,
f.close()
```

Can you tell me what to to, to make the content of the `.zip` file, go in the `.jar`?
If you are a good coder, can you supply me with the code?
I would also like a progress bar thing like the one above while its addinf it, but that one, I got from internet, so I'm not sure how to code those myself.

Greets

Comment: You can just download the ZIP(.zip) file and rename it to JAR(.jar) file.

Answer (score 0):

.jar files are basically standard .zip files with a different ending, so you should be able to add files using the zipfile module.
http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Comment: i read it, but cant figure out how it works, they just put a code and explain what it does, if i type in the code, i get errors